# Detect when child is hovered by parent mouse event

Tags: angular

I have a child element that has `pointer-events: none` and I want to re-enable the `pointer-events` when the child is hovered using the parent element mouse event.

The problem that I cannot get the proper function, I tried a couple of solutions but none of them worked. I prepared this stackblitz which explains it better https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8krjit

**Update** Just to clarify, the pointer-events of the child should not be enabled when the pointer enters the container, but when it enters the child

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the `style.pointerEvents` and `style.cursor` properties on the `nativeElement` by using `@ViewChild`

Give this a try:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('box', { static: false }) box: ElementRef;

  hovered: boolean = false;
  onMouseOver(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.hovered = true;
    (<HTMLDivElement>this.box.nativeElement).style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    (<HTMLDivElement>this.box.nativeElement).style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }

  onMouseOut(e) {
    this.hovered = false;
    (<HTMLDivElement>this.box.nativeElement).style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    (<HTMLDivElement>this.box.nativeElement).style.cursor = 'none';
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log('Box Clicked');
  }
}
```

And in template:

```
<div 
  class="container" 
  (mouseover)="onMouseOver($event)" 
  (mouseout)="onMouseOut($event)">
    <div 
    #box 
    class="box"
    [class.hovered]="hovered" 
    (click)="onClick()">
  </div>
</div>

<h3>mouseover the box: {{hovered}}</h3>
```

---

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-pointer-events-on-div-on-hover?file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I was looking for. your solution enables it as soon as the mouse enters the container, however it should enable the `pointer-events` only when the mouse enters the box. there should be some calculation I guess

Comment: The `pointer-events` of the child should not be enabled when the pointer enters the container, but when it enters the child

Comment: Your child (`box`) won't be able to listen to `mouseover` and `mouseout` events unless `pointer-events: none;` is applied on it. You'll have to get rid of that in order to get the events triggered. Check the stackblitz again. I've updated it.

Comment: No, you misunderstood my question, check this https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-scrollbar/, try to scroll when the pointer is over the scrollbar, you can't, that's why `pointer-events` must be off until the container turns it on using `mouseover`. this should be possible using some calculations. here is a plugin that made it http://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/ but it is difficult to spot how he got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution using `mousemove` event instead of `mouseover`, here is a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvfzfy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event, box)">
      <div #box class="box" [class.hovered]="hovered"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  hovered = false;

  onMouseMove(e, box) {
    const rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.hovered = isWithinBounds(e, rect);
  }
}

function isWithinBounds(e: any, rect: ClientRect): boolean {
  return (
    e.clientX >= rect.left &&
    e.clientX <= rect.left + rect.width &&
    e.clientY >= rect.top &&
    e.clientY <= rect.top + rect.height
  );
}
```